# Problem sending a POST Request with Parameters From a Java app

Tags: java, html, post

There's a web page with a search engine:

http://www.nukat.edu.pl/cgi-bin/gw_48_1_12/chameleon?sessionid=2010010122520520752&skin=default&lng=pl&inst=consortium&search=KEYWORD&function=SEARCHSCR&SourceScreen=NOFUNC&elementcount=1&pos=1&submit=TabData

I want to use its search engine from a java application.

Currently I'm trying to send a very simple request - only one field filled and no logical operators.

This is my code:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL( nukatSearchUrl );
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    urlConn.setDoInput( true );
    urlConn.setDoOutput( true );
    urlConn.setUseCaches( false );
    urlConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( urlConn.getOutputStream() ) );
    String content = "t1=" + URLEncoder.encode( "Duma Key", "UTF-8" );
    out.write( content );
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( urlConn.getInputStream() ) );

    String rcv = null;
    while ( ( rcv = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
        System.out.println( rcv );
    }
    fd.close();
    in.close();
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    throw new SearchEngineException( "NukatSearchEngine.search() : " + ex.getMessage() );
}
```

Unfortunateley what I keep getting is the main site - looks like this:

`<cant post the link to the main site :/>`

Not the search results I'm expecting.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked if bots are allowed to use their search engine?

Answer (score 2):

The URL may be wrong or your request is likely incomplete. You need to check the HTML source (rightclick page > *View Source*) and use the same URL as definied in the `<form action>` and gather **all** request parameters (including those from hidden input fields and the button which you intend to "press"!) for use in your query string.

That said, doing so is in most cases a policy violation and may result in your IP become blacklisted. Please check their `robots.txt` and the "Terms of use" -if any, I don't understand Polish. [Their `robots.txt`](http://www.nukat.edu.pl/robots.txt) at least says that **everyone is disallowed to access the entire website programmatically**. Use it on your own risks. You've been warned. Better contact them and ask if they have any public webservice and then use it instead.

You can always spoof the `user-agent` request header with a real-looking string as extracted from a real webbrowser to minimize the risk to get recognized as a bot as pointed out by Bozho here, but you can still get caught on based on the visitor patterns/statistics.

Answer (score 2):

I wound't go any further with this after reading BalusC's answer. Here are, however, a few pointers, if you don't worry of being blacklisted:

- set the `User-Agent` header to pretend being a browser. for example

  ```
  urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6 GTB6");
  ```
- you can use a simulation of a human user in firefox, using [Selenium WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/wiki/GettingStarted)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see all activity that you need to replicate is the [Live HTTP Headers Firefox Extension](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/). To see all form elements on the page, [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) is useful. Finally, I often use a fake server that I control to see what the browser is sending, and compare to my application. I rolled my own, just a small Java server that prints out everything sent to it - inverse telnet, if you will.

Another note is that some sites deny access based on the User-Agent, i.e. you might need to get your application to pretend it's Firefox. This is very bad practice, and a little dishonest. As BalusC mentioned, check their usage policy and robots.txt! I would also recommend asking permission if you intend to spread your application around.

Finally, I happen to be working on something similar and you might find the following code useful (it writes a mapping of key -> lists of values to the correct POST format):

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            boolean first = false;
            for(Entry<String,List<String>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
                for(String value : entry.getValue()) {
                    if(first) {
                        first = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        builder.append("&");
                    }
                    builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));   
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            return false;
        }
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(builder.toString());
            wr.flush();
            conn.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the user-agent it could also be using cookies to check that the search is being sent from the search page.

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is good for automating form submission including handling any cookies and pretending to be a browser.